# Duda con parametros en funcion javascript

Tags: javascript, vue.js

En este código tengo un `file-input` para cargar un archivo adjunto. Cuando cargo un archivo, se ejecuta la funcion `@change="filesChange"` (la funcion es llamada asi segun la documentacion, no pasa ningun parametro).

```
<tab-pane v-for="(item, index) in idiomas" :key="index">
    ...
        <h4>Imágen de encabezado</h4>
        <file-input @change="filesChange" class="my-1"></file-input>
  ...
  </tab-pane>
```

La funcion `filesChange` está definida como un `method` asi (acá SI aparece un parametro llamado ´´files´´):

```
filesChange(files) {
  this.dataDashboard.imgEncabezado.push(files);
},
```

Ahora, tengo un problema con los parametros. Como pueden ver, al llamar a `filesChange` no tengo que pasarle ningun parametro. Pero ahora, yo quiero pasarle un parametro extra, el `index` de la iteración.

Pruebo haciendo:

```
@change="filesChange(files,index)"
```

Y recibo un error, que `files` no está definido. También probé pasarle `@change="filesChange(index)"`.

Pero no recibo los parametros como espero.

```
filesChange(files,index) {
  console.log("tengo files ",files," e index",index)
}
```

Este console me imprime en `files` lo que espero que venga de `index`, y en index me devuelve undefined.

Como puedo hacer para pasarle como parametro tanto `index` como `files`? (si me explican de donde sale `files` en la declaración de la función, también me serviría porque no entiendo de donde sale dicho parametro/variable)

Muchas gracias

EDIT:

> este es el ejemplo del que me estoy agarrando https://nuxt-argon-dashboard-pro-laravel.creative-tim.com/documentation

```
<template>
  <file-input @change="filesChange"></file-input>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        files: []
      }
    },
    methods: {
      filesChange(files) {
        this.files = files
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Es vue2, vue3? Además, no olvides que en el título debés especificar cuál es tu duda ;)

Comment: @padaleiana es vue 2 sobre nuxt, pero entendi que mi duda es unicamente sobre JS ya que lo que no entiendo es porque puedo llamar a la funcion ``filesChange`` sin pasarle parametros, y que en la declaracion, la funcion sepa qué parametro tiene que utilizar. No se me ocurre como titular la pregunta, porque realmente no sé ni cual es mi duda :/

Comment: @padaleiana En cuanto entienda un poco mejor que es lo que estoy buscando, la modifico. Me confunde mucho que ``files`` no aparezca en el template, y la funcion la reconozca como el adjunto. Si yo tuviera declarada la variable ``files`` y la paso como parametro, seria facil para mi pasar un segundo parametro y redefinir la funcion ``filesChange``. El tema es que ese parametro "fantasma" (que nunca es pasado en la llamada de la funcion) me confunde y no se como agregar un segundo parametro.

Comment: "la funcion es llamada asi segun la documentacion" que documentacion?

Comment: @gbianchi esta es la documentacion, https://nuxt-argon-dashboard-pro-laravel.creative-tim.com/documentation/components/forms.html y el ejemplo al que hago referencia lo acabo de agregar como edit al pie de la pregunta

Comment: Es que no estás llamando a la función cuando pones `@change="filesChange"`, estás pasándole el *handler* de tu función `filesChange` al método que ejecuta vue cuando se dispara ese evento, y es ese método que ejecuta vue el que llama a tu función, a través de su handler, pasándole los parámetros necesarios. En ningún momento estás haciendo una llamada tú, puesto que en ningún momento estás poniendo los paréntesis `()`, que son lo que realmente llama a la función.

Comment: Todo esa nueva informacion, hace que tu pregunta sea totalmente distinta ;)

Comment: prueba así -> @change="filesChange($event, index)"

Comment: Gracias a todos, efectivamente es como dices @Benito-B, y efectivamente puedo pasarle el parametro que requiero si hago lo que indica LPZadkiel (tengo mucho que leer porque no entiendo bien todo esto que sucede). Perdón por formular una pregunta tan mal, no sé si tendría sentido modificarla o lo mejor es eliminarla.

Comment: Edítala, @AgustinG. Cualquier otra persona puede tener la misma duda y tú ya has dado con la solución! Edita la pregunta y recopila toda la información que te ayudó en una respuesta, y luego podrás aceptarla. Así podrás ayudar a otra gente que tenga el mismo problema que tú con el conocimiento obtenido aquí. Sería una pena que el conocimiento y el esfuerzo de esta pregunta se pierdan :)